# Method of least squares

Tags: numerical-methods

> Consider the non-linear equation $x^3 = 3375$. The real solution is given by $x^* = 15$. The iteration sequence $\{x^{(k)}\}$ has the convergence order $p$, if
>
> $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} {||x^{(k+1)} - x^*||_2 \over ||x^{(k)} - x^*||_2^p} = C$$
>
> for $C \ge 0$. Determine the parameters $p$ and $C$ numerical by using $x^{(0)} = 1$ and $k_{max} = 16$. To do so, assume that
>
> $$\log||x^{(k+1)} - x^*||_2 \approx \log(C||x^{(k)} - x^*||_2^p)$$
>
> and solve the problem of least squares.

The only thing I know about the problem / method of least squares is that it has something to do with minimizing $1/2||Ax - b||_2^2$, and that is done by finding an $x \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $A^*Ax = A^*b$.

But I don't see how to apply this here. Could anybody explain to me what I have to do actually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last equation should read
$$
\log\|x^{(k+1)}-x^*\| \approx p·\log\|x^{(k)}-x^*\|+c
$$
or 
$$
\log e_{k+1}=p·\log e_k+c
$$
where $c=\log C$ and $e_k=\|x^{(k)}-x^*\|$. This can be treated by standard linear regression for the pairs $(x_k,y_k)=(\log e_k,\log e_{k+1})$.

Graphically you would have to determine the slope in a log-log-plot of the points $(e_k,e_{k+1})$

Answer (score 1):

Despite being a bit confused myself by the problem description, I'll take a stab at it:

The only way I see a least-squares problem arising out of this is if you construct the functional:

$$
f(p,C)=\sum_{k=k_{min}}^{k_{max}} \Big[\frac{|x^{(k+1)}-x_*|^p}{|x^{(k)}-x_*|}-C\Big]^2
$$

which you can minimise by requiring $f$ to be stationary with respect to $p$ and $C$, i.e.,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}=0$$

and solve the system of non-linear equations with a 2-D analogue of Newton's Method.

What confuses me however, is the iteration sequence for $x^{(k+1)}$

$$\log||x^{(k+1)} - x^*||_2 \approx ||x^{(k)} - x^*||_2^p$$

because I don't see how that converges to $x_*$ for any value of $p$.

Comment: It doesn't, I just wrote it down wrongly and corrected it now. Sorry!

Comment: Ah OK. That changes things quite a bit. The solution below by Lutzl is the way to go.